Invalid conversion from runtime type ExternalDataSource to System.Callable
I need to invoke specific method of class at runtime in Apex. I used callable interface for that.
"ExternalDataSource" Class
public class ExternalDataSource extends ExternalDataSourceInterface implements Callable {

    public override Map<String, Object> executeReadOperation(String soql, String sObj) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => Database.query(soql)
        };
        return response;
    }

    public override Map<String, Object> executeWriteOperation(String sObj, Map<String, Object> data) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Write operation executed successfully'
        };
        return response;
    }

    public override Map<String, Object> getDescribeData(String sObj) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new Map<String, Object>{
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Describe data fetched successfully'
        };
        return response;
    }

    public Object call(String action, Map<String, Object> args) {
        if (action == 'executeReadOperation' ) {
            return executeReadOperation((String) args.get('soql'), (String) args.get('sObj'));
        } else if (action == 'executeWriteOperation') {
            return executeWriteOperation((String) args.get('sObj'), (Map<String, Object>) args.get('data'));
        } else if (action == 'getDescribeData') {
            return getDescribeData((String) args.get('sObj'));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('Method not found or invalid parameters: ' + action);
        }
    }
     
}

ExternalDataSourceInterface Class
public abstract class ExternalDataSourceInterface {    
    public abstract Map<String, Object> executeReadOperation(String soql, String sObj);
    public abstract Map<String, Object> executeWriteOperation(String sObj, Map<String, Object> data);
    public abstract Map<String, Object> getDescribeData(string sObj);
    
    
}

DynamicClassInvoker class
public class DynamicClassInvoker {
    /**
     * Dynamically loads a class and invokes a predefined method.
     * Note: This method assumes the target class implements a shared interface with the method to be invoked.
     * 
     * @param className Fully qualified name of the class.
     * @param methodName Name of the method to invoke.
     * @param params List of parameter values to pass to the method.
     * @return Result of the method invocation.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the class or method cannot be found.
     */
    public static object invokeMethod(String className, String methodName, Map<String,Object> params) {
        if (String.isEmpty(className) || String.isEmpty(methodName)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('Class name and method name cannot be null or empty');
        }

        Type classType = Type.forName(className);
        if (classType == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('Class not found: ' + className);
        }

        Callable classInstance = (Callable) classType.newInstance();
        // if (!(classInstance instanceof Invokable)) {
        //     throw new IllegalArgumentException('Class does not implement the required interface: ' + className);
        // }
        return classInstance.call(methodName, params);
    }

}

I am using DynamicClassInvoker class to invoke the method of class at runtime.
example code.
Map<String, Object> res = (Map<String, Object>) DynamicClassInvoker.invokeMethod(className, 'executeReadOperation', new Map<String,Object>{'soql'=>SOQL, 'sObj'=> sObjApiName});
But getting this error
apexCode: "\t\t\tCallable extension =  (Callable) Type.forName(className).newInstance();\r",
message: 'Invalid conversion from runtime type ExternalDataSource to System.Callable'

Link to docs
I am expecting no error and execution of method in runtime. I have tried changing the type on
Callable classInstance = (Callable) classType.newInstance();
But it didn't work out.
